# How to create connection in SQL developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to create a connection in SQL developer, I got an error like below.

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not
> establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=yNQbbtmpQ5GfAd0chbTrZg==)

[image]

[image]

But I connected Oracle Database 21c Express Edition in SQL plus like the above image.

And In the services below oracle services running
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this, I am new to SQL developer tool.

Comment: Have you installed the Oracle database server product and created a database locally; or have you *only* installed the SQL Developer client? Is there an existing database you've been asked to connect to - and been given connection info for? See [this (old but still relevant) post](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/).

Comment: Put orcl in Service name field instead of SID, if it's the name of the PDB you are trying to connect to.

Comment: @p3consulting what is the username and password I need to use?

Comment: @NirodhaWickramarathna - the error means it can't connect to port 1521 on localhost, which means you don't have a listener running (or, less likely, you have a local firewall blocking it). It isn't getting as far as asking a listener to resolve a specific SID or service name, never mind checking user credentials. Again, SQL Developer *is not a database*. Do you *have* a database, on your PC or that you've been told to connect to?

Comment: @AlexPoole I download and install Oracle Database 21c Express Edition. And I can connect to in by SQL plus like above image

Comment: OK. Check listener service is running, see if it's listening on localhost or your PC name/IP address (`lsnrctl status` - I think that works on Windows, and will show you the service name too), and update the SQL Developer connection settings to match.

Comment: Great! It is connected after changing the Host and port according to "lsnrctl status" output. @AlexPoole Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Check listener service is running, see if it's listening on localhost or your PC name/IP address (lsnrctl status - I think that works on Windows, and will show you the service name too), and update the SQL Developer connection settings to match